# Change Key Icon from a Java File for a custom keyboard

Tags: android, android-custom-keyboard

I got a code to change key label from my java file by

```
keyboard.getKeys().get(0).label= "@";
```

I want to change my key icon as well. But it fails.

```
keyboard.getKeys().get(9).icon= R.Drawable.myicon;
```

an error shows when I do like that saying that is `int` value. I don't how to make this possible in other way.

Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need `drawable` for `icon` as in

```
keyboard.getKeys().get(9).icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(Context, R.drawable.myicon);
```

Comment: wew. That helped me so fast. Thank you

Comment: Glad, I could help :) accept answer if it worked for you and Happy Codinh :)

Comment: `kv.inavlidateKey(9);` is not updating the keyicon. Any other method is there for it?

Comment: Is it because am updating from `label` to `icon`? anyway to update it so